# Compare Variable to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

is it possible to compare a variable to an index in an ArrayList?

```
answer != Doors.get(i))
```

Here im comparing it to the variable in the index, but how do i compare the variable to the actual index. Like if the answer is equal to Doors.get(Index 1, not the actual variable in that slot)

Please help. I cant find any better way to explain.

Comment: Try `indexOf()`. This would be easy to look up in the documentation.

Comment: Uhmmmm... `answer != i` maybe?

Comment: what is i and what is the datatype of your arraylist and answer